# Apache Spark ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting ConnectionRefusedError while running this code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

I installed `Apache Spark 3.4.0`, `Java 20.0.1`, and used winutils.exe for hadoop 3.3.

In C drive I created three folders for spark, hadoop, java.

The directories look like this:

```
C:\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3
C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe
C:\java\jdk
```

I added to the environment variables like this:

```
HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop
JAVA_HOME = C:\java\jdk
SPARK_HOME = C:\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3
```

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I ran the following snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Load Dataset A and Dataset B as Spark DataFrames
dataset_A = spark.read.csv('A.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
dataset_B = spark.read.csv('B.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)

merged_data = dataset_A.join(dataset_B, on='key', how='left')
```

until here there's no problem. But when I run this:

```
merged_data_pandas = merged_data.toPandas()
```

then it throws the connection error message.

Was I supposed to change any configuration files?

Comment: `spark` is already available as a variable in `spark-shell`, you dont need to make a new one... Notice log line `Spark session available as 'spark'`

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I updated the description. when I ran this line, `merged_data_pandas = merged_data.toPandas()` I got that ConnectionRefusedError.

Comment: If you're only reading and merging local CSV files, you don't need Spark and can just use Pandas on its own. Or you can try DuckDB as well. Otherwise, I think you should check for a more exact error from the Spark UI

Comment: Couldn't use pandas or dask, using them I ran into MemroyError as I was dealing with millions of rows.

Comment: Note that I mentioned DuckDB, not Dask. In any case, were you able to open the Spark UI and find any more specific errors here? Or, does your code work with smaller files? You're still getting going to get memory issues since you're only using one machine and loading the same, large files. And maybe this is crashing Spark, causing connection issues

Comment: I figured out the problem. The issue was with writing the data into a file. 
I tried `merged_data.write.parquet('merged_file.parquet')` & `merged_data.write.orc('merged_file.orc')`. I didn't get the ConnectionError but got `Py4JJavaError ` error.
Could you suggest me effective way to write data (around millions or rows) into a file?

Comment: Those are correct, though the "file extension" isn't necessary, as that'll make a folder. `Py4JJavaError` wraps another error. Please edit your question with the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes spark can freeze on a local session, got it happened several times and it helps to restart IDE (I'm using IntelliJ) to get it running again. One additional option could be to verify that the port spark is using is open  and not blocked by firewall.